# Generic Array Java

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming, subtraction

```
/**
 * Compares this array with another array.
 * <p>
 * This is a requirement of the Comparable interface.  It is used to provide
 * an ordering for Array elements.
 * @return a negative value if the provided array is "greater than" this array,
 * zero if the arrays are identical, and a positive value if the
 * provided array is "less than" this array.
 */
@Override

public int compareTo(Array s) {
    // TODO - you fill in here (replace 0 with proper return
    // value).
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(s.size(), mSize); i++) {
        if (this.mArray[i] != s.mArray[i]) {
            return mArray[i] - s.mArray[i];   //FAIL HERE
        }
    }

    return size() - s.size();
}
```

Error: The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) `Array<T>`, `Array`. Can someone please tell me how do I return the difference between the 2 arrays element?

Thank you.

Comment: is your `mArray` array type of int ?

Comment: If Array is you self-defined type, you should change to another name, because it is a class name in JDK.

Comment: private Array<T> [] mArray; it can be any type

Comment: How do you expect the operator `-` to be applied to an `Array` object?

Comment: oh um but i thought what I am doing was subtracting the element of the array.....

Answer (score -1):

You could try doing an `Integer.parseInt()`, if you're certain the array element is an int. Similarly, you could also force a cast.

Method A:

```
if (this.mArray[i] != s.mArray[i]) {
    return Integer.parseInt(mArray[i]) - Integer.parseInt(s.mArray[i]);
}
```

Method B:

```
if (this.mArray[i] != s.mArray[i]) {
    return ((int) mArray[i]) - ((int) s.mArray[i]);
}
```

Just make sure you have the proper `try`/`catch` in place.

Comment: I try to do it but it gives me :   The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Array<T>)

Comment: Try `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mArray[i]))`, etc etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
 return mArray[i] - s.mArray[i];   //FAIL HERE
```

At least you are right about failing here.

You said that `mArray` could be any type (Generic). It should work if the array is a primitive type. You can't expect this line to work if your `mArray` is an array of `String`.

maybe you can break your operation down depending on which data type the array has.

btw, what would you expect if you are "Subtracting" two Strings? 
here's a pseudocode to (hopefully) point you in the right direction

```
if (test if your array is of type int){
  return mArray[i] - s.mArray[i];

}else if (test if your array is String){
  // do what you need...

} // ....whatever data type you expect
```